# Swift Reflection mapping attributes

Tags: swift, reflection

Are there anything look like java reflection in swift or I have to always map one by one attribute like following code?

```
class User: Model {

var name: String

override init(data: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>){
    super.init(data: data)
    self.name = data["name"] as? String
    if let vouchers_count = data["vouchers_count"] as? Int {
        self.vouchers_count = vouchers_count
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use libraries such as [EVReflection](https://github.com/evermeer/EVReflection).

```
import EVReflection

class User: EVObject {
    var name: String = ""
    var vouchers_count: Int = 0
}

let alice = User(json: "{\"name\":\"alice\",\"vouchers_count\":1}")
debugPrint(alice)
/*
    testUser = {
    "name" : "alice",
    "vouchers_count" : 1
    }
*/

let bob = User(json: "{\"name\":\"bob\"}")
debugPrint(bob)
/*
    testUser = {
    "name" : "bob",
    "vouchers_count" : 0
    }
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3 currently only has fairly basic reflection capability using Mirror - as documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/mirror).

In your case you would use it as:

```
let user = User()
user.name = "Michael"
let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: user)
print(mirror)
for case let (label?, value) in mirror.children {
    print ("\(label) \(subjectType) = \(value))
    // ... Prints name String = Michael
}
```

A good article can be found [here](https://appventure.me/2015/10/24/swift-reflection-api-what-you-can-do/).